# CodeIgniter get Session by ID or userID

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Is it possible with CodeIgniter to receive the data of a session only by it's id or a specific userID? `$this->session` is not working because the code is executed by an external API Call.

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#removing-session-data

Comment: You said it's called by an external API Call. Can you further explain ? There might be no session if you're not sending the correct headers.

Comment: you should exactly explain what you want and what you did

Answer (score 2):

```
    $this->session->set_userdata("user_id","10"); //set user id  
    $this->session->userdata("user_id"); //get user id
```

please refer https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print_r($this->session->userdata);
```

or

```
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

Comment: This only works if i call the Webpage as the logged in User. And only for that user you will be able to get the session data

Answer (score 0):

or print_r($this->session->userdata('id')); only one element of the session. but you have to set session data after login in controller :)

Answer (score 0):

here is my suggestion for you.

When you are calling external api than you can also send the login details so you can check it with login system and if the login is successfull than you can store session values in the temp array and fetch that array, thats it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an unique identifier for your session,you should use

> $this->session->session_id

Answer (score 0):

that's what worked for me :

$my_variable = $_SESSION['user']['id'];